# Reference to type 'Freezable' claims it is defined in 'WindowsBase', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using the System.Windows.Media.Media3D namespace to do some matrix math/transformations in my C# console app. I would like to use .NET Core so that my console app can be run in the Linux environment. I am using .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 5 in hopes that these WPF features have been published. I did notice in the .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 5 announcement that WPF won't be fully published until .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 7.

I've included references to PresentationCore and WindowsBase in my .csproj file.

When I try to use dotnet build I get multiple CS7069 errors: Reference to type 'Freezable' claims it is defined in 'WindowsBase', but could not be found.

I peeked inside of the WindowsBase.dll and confirmed that 'Freezable' is defined.

I worry that I will have to write my own library, but I figured I would try asking here first.

An answer to any of my below questions would be greatly appreciated:

1. Is there a way to get rid of these compiler errors and accomplish what I would like to with .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 5? If so, how?
2. Is this something that will require WPF to be fully published in .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 7, even though I don't need any visual elements?
3. Is there a Linux (newest Ubuntu) compatible library that will allow me to use equivalents to Point3D, Vector3D, and RotateTransform3D class methods?

Thank you!

Comment: What matrix and math transformations are you doing? Maybe you can use math.net https://www.mathdotnet.com/

Comment: Out of System.Windows.Media.Media3D I am using: Vector3D, Point3D, RotateTransform3D, RotateTransform3D.Transform, AxisAngleRotation3D, and Vector3D.AngleBetween(). I will checkout math.net. Thanks!

Comment: Ended up just rewriting all of the classes that I needed.